# I am unable to access the apache server in centos 8?

Tags: apache, centos

unable to access the apache server in centos 8

1. dnf install httpd
2. firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=https
3. firewall-cmd --reload

status is fine

```
[root@test ~]# systemctl status httpd
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-10-05 04:36:53 EDT; 1h 38min ago
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
 Main PID: 30730 (httpd)
   Status: "Running, listening on: port 80"
    Tasks: 213 (limit: 23565)
   Memory: 43.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─30730 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─30732 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─30733 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─30734 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           └─30735 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

Oct 05 04:36:53 test.server systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Oct 05 04:36:53 test.server systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Oct 05 04:36:53 test.server httpd[30730]: Server configured, listening on: port 80
```

Main Problen is http:// not working tried in all browser <ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT>

Answer (score 1):

In your step 2 you opened https on the firewall which is port 443 so port 80 will still be blocked by the firewall